# flexbox width inside horizontally scrollable container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a layout for a virtual table.
A virtual table will be placed inside `.table-body` element.
Each table cell has the same flex layout styles as cells in `.table-header` so with the same parent element with they would look the same.
The problem is that the `.table-cell` elements do not stretch `.table-header` width, and `.table-header` element does not stretch the `.table-container` width.

I'm trying to get the `.table-cell`'s to give the width for the `.table-header` and `.table-container`. And the `.table-body` would take up the remaining space in the `.table-container`

Here is **[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flexbox-width-inside-y-scrollable-container-msioq?file=/styles.css)** to play with.

```css
.table-wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2);
}

.table-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  /* If you uncomment next line, you see what I'm trying to achieve */
  /* min-width: 1100px; */
  
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);
}

.table-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  
  background: rgba(255, 100, 0, 0.3);
}

.table-cell {
  min-width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.table-body {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <div class="table-container">
    <div class="table-header">
      <div class="table-cell" style="flex: 0 0 180px;">header-cell 1</div>
      <div class="table-cell">header-cell 2</div>
      <div class="table-cell">header-cell 3</div>
      <div class="table-cell">header-cell 4</div>
      <div class="table-cell" style="flex: 0 0 200px;">header-cell 5</div>
      <div class="table-cell">header-cell 6</div>
      <div class="table-cell">header-cell 7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-body">virtual table here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Flexbox is meant for layouts in one dimension. For table layouts, I recommend you use `<table>` or CSS Grid.

Comment: your question is not clear I can't understand what's the relation between the width and a vertical scrollable area.
Did you mean horizontally scrollable area? Can explain more what do you want to do?

Comment: I am trying to create a container for a virtual table. Sorry, it was a typo in the question header. I'll update the question to be more clear.

Comment: table-header and table-container width are limited to the dimension of table-wrapper while table cell are nowrap so they overflow wrapper container. this link could help https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-flow-property. A flex item establishes an independent formatting context for its contents. However, flex items themselves are flex-level boxes, not block-level boxes: they participate in their container’s flex formatting context, not in a block formatting context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the use of `inline-flex` instead of `flex` and define the width using `width` and not `flex-basis`

```css
.table-wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2);
}

.table-container {
  display: inline-flex; /* UPDATED */
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  min-width: 100%; /* UPDATED */
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);
}

.table-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  
  background: rgba(255, 100, 0, 0.3);
}

.table-cell {
  min-width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.table-body {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <div class="table-container">
    <div class="table-header">
      <div class="table-cell" style="flex: 0 0 180px;width:180px;">header-cell 1</div>
      <div class="table-cell">header-cell 2</div>
      <div class="table-cell">header-cell 3</div>
      <div class="table-cell">header-cell 4</div>
      <div class="table-cell" style="flex: 0 0 200px;width:200px;">header-cell 5</div>
      <div class="table-cell">header-cell 6</div>
      <div class="table-cell">header-cell 7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-body">virtual table here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a workaround I found, use `width: min-content;` for both table-header and table-container.
This only work when you get rid of the inline style in the `table-cell`.

```css
.table-wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2);
}

.table-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  width: min-content;
  height: 100%;
  
  /* If you uncomment next line, you see what I'm trying to achieve */
  /* min-width: 1100px; */
  
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);
}

.table-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: min-content;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  
  background: rgba(255, 100, 0, 0.3);
}

.table-cell {
  min-width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.table-body {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <div class="table-container">
    <div class="table-header">
      <div class="table-cell">header-cell 1</div>
      <div class="table-cell">header-cell 2</div>
      <div class="table-cell">header-cell 3</div>
      <div class="table-cell">header-cell 4</div>
      <div class="table-cell" >header-cell 5</div>
      <div class="table-cell">header-cell 6</div>
      <div class="table-cell">header-cell 7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-body">virtual table here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```